# Double integral to polar coordinates, bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to find $\int_0^2 \int_ {\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dydx$.

My idea is to do a transformation to polar coordinates;

$\iint \sqrt{4-r^2} rdrd\theta$, but I'm unsure about the bounds. Plotting the bounds in $f(x,y)$ I realize I'm dealing with the area between a smaller circle centered at (1, 0) and r=1 and a bigger circle centered at (0,0) with r = 2. (Under the ball $\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: You get the bounds simpl by putting the value or taking the limit for each coordinate. For example say $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and say that $x,y \in[0,2]$. Then you look at the maximum and minimum of $r$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. The solution will be an interval because r(x,y) is continuous. So in this case $r\in [0,2]$. You do this for all coordinates. However you must make sure that the integrand is correct. For example for $r=1, \theta=0$ the integrand is 0.  -- Perhaps it is easier to use linearity of the integral and make two integrals. I.e. the difference of two balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that the integral is on the region $R$ between $C_1$ and $C_2$ and $y>0$ with

- $C_1: x^2+y^2=4\,$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $2$
- $C_2: (x-1)^2+y^2=1$ is a circle centered at $(1,0)$ with radius $1$

[$C_1$ and $C_2$ Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D4,%20x%5E2-2x%2By%5E2%3D0)

thus

$$\iint_R \sqrt{4-r^2} rdrd\theta=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} d\theta\int_0^2 \sqrt{4-r^2} rdr-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} d\theta\int_0^{2\cos \theta} \sqrt{4-r^2} rdr$$

indeed

- for $C_1$ we are integrating on a quarter of circle
- for $C_2$ we are integrating on half circle and we have that the circle is defined by

$$x^2+y^2=2x\implies r^2=2r\cos \theta \implies r=2\cos \theta$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate on you how you arrive at $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ aswell as $0$ to $2cos(\theta)$?

Comment: @novo I've just added some comment to explain, make a sketch of the region to better visualize how it works.

Comment: @novo sorry I just realize that we are only integrating on the upper part, I fix

Comment: @novo It doesn't change so much, I'm adding a sketch

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help!

Comment: @novo You are welcome, let me know if you agree with my last set up and if all is clear!

Comment: Yes, the illustration looks fine and helps a lot with the intuition. I'm new to this, and I find the angles which you integrate over confusing sometimes. To make sure that I understood it right: We integrate from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ because our volume of interest is in the first quadrant, is this correct?

Comment: @novo Yes of course, note also that the circle $C_1$ is decribed by $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ whereas  the circle $C_2$ is decribed by $\theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

Comment: How did you get ready=2cos θ. It should be 0 to 2 because upper limit of r in R is 2?

Comment: Can u tell me what exactly you are doing for finding  θ and r

Comment: @Aladdin For the red circle, by trigonometry identity on right triangles, we have that $r=2\cdot \cos \theta$ (see triangle with hypotenuse = diameter =$2$).

Comment: Wait but our integration region is blue part, right? So why are you taking r for C2

Comment: @Aladdin I'm subtracting the half red form one quarter blue.

Comment: Why is r is not calculated for C1?I am not able to understand it

Comment: @Aladdin We are calculating the given integral on the region R as the difference of the region $R_1$ (one quarter blue circle with radius=2) and the region $R_2$ (one half red circle with diameter=2)

Comment: In the region between R1 and R2, if I take any random point and calculate  it's distance from origin then it should give me my limits for r. So it comes zero when the point is still origin and 2 when it is at distance 0Y in Y axis in the region between R1 and R2

Comment: What is wrong with this argument

Comment: @Aladdin We can of course calculate only one integral. In that case $r$ varies from $2\cos \theta$ to $2$ that is  $$\iint_R \sqrt{4-r^2} rdrd\theta=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} d\theta\int_{2\cos \theta}^2 \sqrt{4-r^2} rdr$$

Comment: Last doubt, how you took  2cos θ to 2? What's wrong with 0 to 2? What was your process for obtaining 2cos θ to 2.Sorry if I am bothering you  but I am really confused with the limits

Comment: @Aladdin Look at sketch in my answer. As you can see for a point on the shaded area we need r between $2\cos \theta$ and $2$.